# Looping on/off switch (10 s on, 0.5 s off)

Tags: relay, dc, 24v

I bought a 24 V shower booster pump,

[image]

and it has this crazy behaviour that it shuts down after 10 - 12 seconds.
When I restart the pump, it starts again for 10 - 12 seconds.

It is useless now and pumps that do not have this "feature" are outside my price range.

A simple solution would be to restart the pump every 10 seconds, with 0.5 second paused.

But how to make a looping relay that is NC for longer time and NO for a really short time??

Edit:
No, no schematic of the pump, just + and -.
Inside sealed with epoxy.

No, not a pressure switch.
If I limit the incoming water flow it should take different time to reach pressure.
Always about 12 seconds (not stopwatch)

Thanks for thinking with me, but obviously I thought of those.

Sure, there is flow sensor to start the booster pump when the water starts.
Why the heck they built something inside to stop after short time??
And don't restart until the water stops, and starts again, or the power is interrupted.

I found with the help for correct search terms the following hardware:
[image]

It can do continuous loop at different timings for stop and start.

I totally agree that this is not the best way.
The pump should work continuous without this type of trouble.
Thing is, dry testing one doesn't do for long 10 second period, the fault is not detected.
After installing, there is no longer any opertunity for return or warranty

Note:
It's not being used for shower, but to boost water pressure coming from a deep well pump.
After 35 meter that is pressure too low to be used for spraying the plants outside

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the pressure switch that needs adjusting?

Comment: Pump and wiring specs and diagrams pls.

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me. I edit the post to be more clear.

Comment: Based on the additional information that you provided, it might be that the pump stops because it can not cover 35m - it does say 15m on the label. There is likely some kind of security getting into play.  You may want to try it with a source that already has a proper pressure.  Maybe it stops after 12 seconds because that is the maximum time it should operate to pump water from 15m down to the proper pressure.  If it doesn't it may just go into a security mode and not try again.  *  Also note that there are clear water pumps and dirty water pumps. *  Use water in a tub as source to test.

Comment: Second, as you are using it for irrigation, do you allow the pump to reach the output pressure?  Is there enough restriction on the water output?

Comment: There is a 340 watt deep well pump who is rated for max 50 meter head. As result the pressure that comes from the sweep well pump isn't great. The booster pump doesn't pull from 15 meter but it does pull, making a push-pull situation where the deep well pump gets help above the ground.  Output pressure is as max as it can give.  Restricted flow doesn't change the behaviour. Even from input (water pressure it receives) I can close and open or open 1/4, 1/2 etc. Same for the output. Both should have influence in the 12 seconds if it is pressure related.

Comment: How much restricted is a shower?? That greatly depending on the type of shower. Same for a water tap. It's not rocket science, just an inline pump, that have received too much tinkering in China. This might be malfunction unit. It might be feature. Doesn't matter. It is what it is and there isn't budget to buy new. Better make it work the way it is.

Comment: @ie_top, Thanks for thinking with me. I see stackexchange doesn't do PM. That would made it more easy :-)  I cant make it different from what it is, and with just 2 wires and loads of epoxy seal, impossible to find why it's doing this.  There is no sensor except flow, who works with simple magnet. No pressure sensor or anything special. The price range already excludes this.  The setup is far from Ideal, 2*345w solar panels, 200Ah@24v lead acid to replace a 3.5hp gasoline pump... 600 watt would have given somewhat similar pressure. 340w is just short. The 12 seconds it works, it's good.

Comment: That is, adding the 90 watt pump to the pressure. When the looping tool arrives, we will know if it will produce magic smoke or rocks :-)

Answer (score 0):

## How to make a looping relay that is NC for longer time and NO for a really short time??

A 555 timer IC with a relay allows you to do this.  You can find modules that already do this for you, a potentiometer and jumpers help you set the right durations.

The 555 timer IC has been around in decades and comes in different flavors - there are some that work up to 18V at least.

http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/555-on-24v.html shows how to hook one on to a 24V supply directly (but it will not be able to drive your pump without a relay).

A google search for "555 timer with relay 24V" gives quite a few results.  You can find ready to use modules for less than $10.

Keep in mind that you can not tune the 555 time for a duty cycle between 0 and 100%, it can only be tuned for about half the range.  By using the NC or NO output of the relay you can achieve the functional duty-cycle that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Being new to the forum I can not upvote the answer, thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped find a proper module.